# How can I save each column in a csv into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

I'm trying to make each column into a list the following way:

```
f = open('file.csv', 'r') 
a = [float(item.split('.')[0]) for item in f]
b = [float(item.split('.')[1]) for item in f]
```

When I print `a` I get a list with all the values of the first column, 
but when I print `b` it shows an empty list. I tried changing the columns of a with that of `b` and `a` gives me the column I'm asking for, just after the first defined list it keeps showing empty lists.

Comment: You need to rewind the file, or close and reopen

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv

list_a = []
list_b = []

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='.')
    next(reader, None)  # Skip the header.
    for a, b in reader:
        list_a.append(float(a))
        list_b.append(float(b))
```

---

Or with the `zip` trick:

```
with open('file.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='.')
    next(reader, None)  # Skip the header.
    list_a, list_b = zip(*(map(float, row) for row in reader))
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = [float(item.split('.')[0]) for item in f]` reads everything from the file. There is nothing left for the second list comprehension. You must close the file and open it again, e.g.:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    a = [float(item.split('.')[0]) for item in f] 
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    b = [float(item.split('.')[1]) for item in f]
```

But it is even better to read the file only once and process both a's and b's in one loop:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    a, b = zip(*[map(float, item.split('.')) for item in f])
```